# javafx populate listview dynamically

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2, observablelist

Javafx newbie here.. I need help with the best way to populate listview. Here is my setup..

I am developing UI tool that is supposed to track the number of virtual machines running in my environment. I get a callback whenever a machine comes up or goes down. How do I update listview based on that data. Controller code -

```
public class MainOverviewController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> devicesListView; // Points to the listview

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Machines connected");

    devicesListView.setItems(items);

    ...
}
```

Callback code where I am getting the virtual machine notifications -

```
class VMChangeListener extends vmlistener
{
...

@Override
public void vmStarted(VM vm)
{
    vms.add(vm);
}

@Override
public void vmDisconnected(VM vm)
{
    vms.remove(vm);
}
```

Now my question is, whats the best way to update observablelist, items, from vmStarted and vmDisconnected functions. I could pass the observablelist to the VMChangeListener or use some sort of callbacks? Should I do this in seperate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainOverviewController extends vmListener implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private ListView<VM> devicesListView; // Points to the listview

    @Override
    public void vmStarted(final VM vm)
    {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                devicesListView.getItems().add(vm);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void vmDisconnected(final VM vm)
    {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                devicesListView.getItems().remove(vm);
            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```